# Select index based on another array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 5
)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => Test1
            [2] => Location1
            [3] => Email1
            [4] => Name1
            [5] => Address1
            [6] => Age1
            [7] => Gender1
            [8] => Phone1
            [9] => Website1
            [10] => Cell1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Test2
            [2] => Location2
            [3] => Email2
            [4] => Name2
            [5] => Address2
            [6] => Age2
            [7] => Gender2
            [8] => Phone2
            [9] => Website2
            [10] => Cell2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => Test3
            [2] => Location3
            [3] => Email3
            [4] => Name3
            [5] => Address3
            [6] => Age3
            [7] => Gender3
            [8] => Phone3
            [9] => Website3
            [10] => Cell3
        )
)
```

Now i have to select 1,3,4 and 5 index value from each second array. How can i do this without two loops. I know i will have to use one but i don't want to use two loops

Output Required

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => Test1
            [3] => Email1
            [4] => Name1
            [5] => Address1

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Test2
            [3] => Email2
            [4] => Name2
            [5] => Address2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => Test3
            [3] => Email3
            [4] => Name3
            [5] => Address3
        )
)
```

Comment: without loops! I think this can't be done :(

Comment: Why do you not want to use more than one loop?

Comment: using two loops is common. I want to know if there is any php built in function or logic so that i can achieve it

Comment: Using two loops isn't a bad thing.  It won't make it any slower than one loop and some hackish code.  On the upside, code readability will be better.

Comment: Possible, but possibly not worthwhile: `array_intersect_key` and a callback for `array_map`.

Comment: `array_map` in the rescue. A powerful tool which people often forget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using one loop, [`array_flip`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php), and [`array_intersect_key`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php), you can do it like this:

```
$array_one = array(1, 3, 4, 5);

$array_two = array(
    array(1 => 'Test1', 'Location1', 'Email1', 'Name1', 'Address1', 'Age1', 'Gender1', 'Phone1', 'Website1', 'Cell1'),
    array(1 => 'Test2', 'Location2', 'Email2', 'Name2', 'Address2', 'Age2', 'Gender2', 'Phone2', 'Website2', 'Cell2'),
    array(1 => 'Test3', 'Location3', 'Email3', 'Name3', 'Address3', 'Age3', 'Gender3', 'Phone3', 'Website3', 'Cell3')
); 

$array_one_flip = array_flip($array_one);
foreach($array_two as $k => $v) {
    $result[] = array_intersect_key($v, $array_one_flip);
}

print_r($result);
```

The result would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => Test1
            [3] => Email1
            [4] => Name1
            [5] => Address1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Test2
            [3] => Email2
            [4] => Name2
            [5] => Address2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => Test3
            [3] => Email3
            [4] => Name3
            [5] => Address3
        )

)
```

Comment: `array_intersect_key` uses the key value's and doesn't achieve OP's desired result.

Comment: Yes i have tested it is not working according to my requirement as you can see it is always selecting first 4 columns

Comment: Yeah, I overlooked that as well. I've modified my answer to address that issue.

Answer (score 3):

You could try it with [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php):

```
$keys = array_flip($keys_array);    // flip the keys array for matching with array_intersect_key
$result = array();
foreach ($content_array as $arr)
{
  $result[] = array_intersect_key($arr, $keys);
}
```

[Working example on codepad](http://codepad.org/ecnJDSBy). Thanks @Michael Irigoyen for the arrays...

Comment: it is not selecting the desired result. Please test it

Comment: @raheel shan Have you flipped your keys array?

Comment: @raheel shan It does work, see my edit / the example on codepad.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an `array_map` function like this:

```
$keys_to_keep = array(1, 3, 4, 5);
$key_diff_array = array_fill_keys($keys_to_keep, 'not used');

$array; // your main array you want to filter assume value has been set elsewhere

$filtered_array = array_map(function ($value) use $key_diff_array {
    return array_intersect_key($value, $key_diff_array);
}, $array);
```

Comment: I don't see $array in array_map?

Answer (score 0):

using one loop:

```
<?php
 $selection = array(1, 3, 4, 5);
 for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){

 reset($selection);
 $first = current($selection);
 $newarray[$i][$first] = $array[$i][$first];

 $next = next($selection);
 $newarray[$i][$next] = $array[$i][$next];

 $next = next($selection);
 $newarray[$i][$next] = $array[$i][$next];

 $next = next($selection);
 $newarray[$i][$next] = $array[$i][$next];
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($newarray);
```

Comment: Very inefficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You might also find this Note about array_flip useful.

Ensure that $array1 has values that can be accepted as array keys when flipped.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

> The key can either be an integer or a string. The value can be of any type.
>
> Additionally the following key casts will occur:
>
> Strings containing valid integers will be cast to the integer type. E.g. the key "8" will actually be stored under 8. On the other hand "08" will not be cast, as it isn't a valid decimal integer.
> Floats are also cast to integers, which means that the fractional part will be truncated. E.g. the key 8.7 will actually be stored under 8.
> Bools are cast to integers, too, i.e. the key true will actually be stored under 1 and the key false under 0.
> Null will be cast to the empty string, i.e. the key null will actually be stored under "".
> Arrays and objects can not be used as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: Illegal offset type.
> If multiple elements in the array declaration use the same key, only the last one will be used as all others are overwritten.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php

> array_flip() returns an array in flip order, i.e. keys from trans become values and values from trans become keys.
>
> Note that the values of trans need to be valid keys, i.e. they need to be either integer or string. A warning will be emitted if a value has the wrong type, and the key/value pair in question will not be included in the result.
>
> If a value has several occurrences, the latest key will be used as its value, and all others will be lost.